# Add a field to Product Categories

Tags: magento2, category

Hey guys,
I want to add a field to the product categories. I created an EAV attribute and added the field, but the value of the field is not saved (It's not persistent).
I think the problem is that the field is not linked to the EAV attribute.
The code is as follows, Please show me the missing puzzle.
Thank you for your helps in advance :-)

---

[image: Project Files]

**category_form.xml:**

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <fieldset name="general">

        <field name="showall_label">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">32</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">"Show All" Label</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

**InstallData.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Amaj\MegaMenu\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Category setup factory
     *
     * @var CategorySetupFactory
     */
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

        //$categorySetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'my_attribute' );

        $categorySetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'showall_label',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => '"Show All" Label',
                'group'        => '',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'global'       => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible'      => true,
                'required'     => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'sort_order'   => 100
            ]
        );

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

---

Results:

EAV attr is being created in the DB and the field is being shown in the admin panel:
[image]
But when the field is filled and "save" is pressed, everything would be saved except for my field.