# Magento 2 - Add a custom field to Product Categories

Tags: magento2, category, attributes

There's a question I asked [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148440/add-a-field-to-product-categories) before, but got no answers.
Please tell me if [this tutorial](https://gielberkers.com/adding-custom-category-attributes-magento-2-1/) (which I can't get it to work) is complete or not.

Thanks for your helps in advance.

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: **@Khoa TruongDinh**: Thanks for helping. It's 2.1